# Array feature with variable in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hello guys i have seen a code which makes me feel doubted..The code is

```
from sqlalchemy import *

db = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db')


metadata = BoundMetaData(db)

users = Table('users', metadata,

Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
Column('name', String(40)),

Column('age', Integer),

Column('password', String),
)



users.create()

i = users.insert()

i.execute(name='Mary', age=30, password='secret')

i.execute({'name': 'John', 'age': 42},

{'name': 'Susan', 'age': 57},

 {'name': 'Carl', 'age': 33})

s = users.select()
rs = s.execute()

row = rs.fetchone()

print 'Id:', row[0]

print 'Name:', row['name']

print 'Age:', row.age

print 'Password:', row[users.c.password]
```

Here i know print 'id:' `row[0]` prints the first value from the field row and `row['name']`prints the name value from row and `row.age` prints the age value from row.But in the case of password you can see that the condition is not the above its given as `row[users.c.password]`.

I just need to know the use of c here .Is c an object member of the class ..I havnt seen the varibale c decalired .Is it missing from code or something ..

Sorry for a long question .Any help would be appreciated .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

.c is a namespace of `Column` objects linked to a parent selectable.  Any `Table` has one as do `Select` objects and such:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, MetaData, Integer

m = MetaData()
t = Table('t', m, Column('x', Integer))
print(t.c.x)
```

also it seems like you're reading some really ancient tutorial which I would advise against.  The [sqlalchemy core tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html) is the best way to get the most accurate information.

there's examples of using .c at: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns